# pandas grouping based on hour to get intra day variability

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame hourly time series of rainfall at 3 locations.The head and tail provides the details of the data as below. In order to understand the diurnal variation of precipitation, I would like to club all the hourly data from all days and all years.

```
hourly_series.head()
                           loc1_data  loc2_data loc3_data
2013-10-01 05:30:00+00:00        0.5          1          1
2013-10-01 06:30:00+00:00        NaN        NaN        NaN
2013-10-01 07:30:00+00:00        NaN        NaN        NaN
2013-10-01 08:30:00+00:00          0          0          0
2013-10-01 09:30:00+00:00        NaN        NaN        NaN

[5 rows x 3 columns]
hourly_series.tail()
                           loc1_data  loc2_data  loc3_data
2014-01-01 00:30:00+00:00        7.5          1          5
2014-01-01 01:30:00+00:00          0          0          0
2014-01-01 02:30:00+00:00          0          2          0
2014-01-01 03:30:00+00:00          0        4.5          0
2014-01-01 04:30:00+00:00          1          0          0
```

I tried

```
hourly_grouped = hourly_series.groupby([(lambda x:x.year,lambda x:x.month, lambda x: x.time)])
```

However, I could'nt achieve the desired output. I am new to the pandas package.

Comment: What was the output from your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
hourly_series['hour'] = hourly_series.index
hourly_series['hour'] = hourly_series['hour'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
hourly_series.groupby(['hour']).var() # Or any other stats function
```

Comment: Thanks@Shravan. another quick question is how do i resample between two given timestamps to arrive at daily rainfall.For example I would like to calculate daily rainfall by summing all not NaN values between 7:30 given day to 7:30 next day.NOTE there could be more than 24 values in the timeseries as the frequency is not hourly.

Comment: Hello!  If you are looking for daily sum between some start and end date this should work.

start = pd.to_datetime('2012-05-30 00:00:00')
end = pd.to_datetime('2012-06-01 00:00:00')


hourly_series['day'] = hourly_series.index
hourly_series['day'] = hourly_series['day'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
hourly_series[start:end].groupby(['day']).sum(skipna = True)